# How to publish a node modules for build results?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am using npm to install dependencies a lot and enjoined using it. When I run `npm install` it will install all dependencies and I can see there is build results for each dependency either in `dist` or `lib` directory. Recently I published one of my node modules on `npmjs.com`. But when clients install my dependency, my build results didn't get built. How can I let build run when others install my dependency?

Comment: If you want the lib and dist files to be available then they need to be included in your module. Provided they are not in the .npmignore file they should be in your module. Do you have a link?

Comment: these modules that have `lib` or `dist` folder usually their code is written in typescipt and compiled in the `dist` or `lib` folders, if your module is written in pure javascript you don't need to build your code in those folders.

Comment: I want to package my javascript codes into a big minified js file for client use. How can I do that in npm module?